# How to compile Mono as generic linux installer package

Tags: c#, linux, deployment, mono

In the past the Mono team has provided a generic linux installer that was working on several linux distributions (without dependencies on system libraries).

How can i compile mono on my dev machine so i can make a tar package and deploy it on a linux user account as parallel environment? I dont have root nor developer tools on the target machines and all have different glibc versions, etc.